# How to let DOM elements stack and overflow horizontally instead of vertically in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Do I need a container that is extra wide and set the elements to inline display or float or something? What if I have two rows, each taking 50% height?

What if the number of elements is undetermined? How to determine the container width?

It seems very hard with div. Do I have to use table?

Also, it seems very hard in pure css, as it's confusing and hard to control the relative width and height at the same time. Do I have to use JS?

What is the easiest and most elegant way of doing this?

Comment: If my answer did answer your question, please vote for it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds very much like you want to use the CSS attribute: [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

With flex box, you can define the max and min width and height and the max/min number of elements before they fall onto a new line.

The beauty of it is, you let the browser calculate widths, you just define the max, min, margins and padding.

And its all CSS, no javascript required

Take a look at the examples at css tricks and have a play about with it. That link is relatively old so some of the vendor prefixes may not be needed any more.

Hope this helps!

EDIT: Additional info on the flex attribute can be found at [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

Comment: IE's Browser compatibility for flexbox miy cause some problems... if using slightly older versions http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use Masonry (http://masonry.desandro.com/ )

You can line up your divs horizontally but you will run into problems if they don't have a set height as they would start to stagger like steps once they extend to the second/third line etc...

Comment: I don't see horizontal layout in their demo.